# wget - only getting .listing file in every sub-dir

Tags: wget, recursive

if I use the command

```
wget --no-remove-listing -P ...../debugdir/gnu/<dir>/ ftp:<ftp-site>/gnu/<dir>/
```

I will get the `.listing` file of that directory. But I have to step through each subsequent sub-directories to get the whole structure. Is there a way to get the `.listing` file from all (sub)directories with one command?

Also, I have noticed that the file `index.html` is automatically generated after every access. Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

The thing is that I always found Bash processing slow, but after some profiling I found that the largest delay is in getting each `.listing` file from subsequent sub-directories.

Example: checking for specific file extensions in the GNU tree takes about 320 seconds of which 290 seconds are for processing the above `wget` command.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to build an index of a FTP site, that is, to list all of the subdirectories and files on the site without actually retrieving them, you can do this:

```
wget -r -x --no-remove-listing --spider ftp://ftp.example.com/
```

where,

- -r => recursive (i.e, visit subdirectories)
- -x => force mirror subdirectories to be created on client
- --no-remove-listing => leave ".listing" files in each subdirectory
- --spider => visit but do not retrieve files

This will create a sparse directory tree of identical structure on the client as the server, containing only ".listing" files showing the contents  (the result of "ls -l") for each directory. If you want to digest that into a single list of path-qualified file names (like you would get from "find . -type f"), then do this at the root of that sparse directory tree:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
( find . -maxdepth 999 -name .listing -exec \
awk '$1 !~ /^d/ {C="date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" -d \"" $6 " " $7 " " $8 "\""; \
C | getline D; printf "%s\t%12d\t%s%s\n", D, $5, gensub(/[^/]*$/,"","g",FILENAME), $9}' \
{} \; 2>/dev/null ) | sort -k4
```

which will give you output like

```
2000-09-27 00:00:00       261149    ./README
2000-08-31 00:00:00       727040    ./foo.txt
2000-10-02 00:00:00      1031115    ./subdir/bar.txt
2000-11-02 00:00:00      1440830    ./anotherdir/blat.txt
```

NB: the "-maxdepth 999" option is not necessary in this use case, I left it in the invocation that I was testing that had an additional constraint: to limit the depth of the tree that was reported. For example, if you scan a site that contains full source trees for several projects, like

```
./foo/Makefile
./foo/src/...
./foo/test/...
./bar/Makefile
./bar/src/...
./bar/test/...
```

then you might only want an outline of the projects and top level directories. In this case,  you would give an option like "-maxdepth 2".

Answer (score 0):

One serious issue with this solution is that '--spider' causes wget to TRANSFER every file but not write any data to disk. This means you will be effectively downloading the entire contents of the FTP server. This can potentially have unwanted consequences such as (but not only): incurring ISP ingress traffic overage fees, disruption to other IP services like VoIP/IPTV/VoD while you saturate your WAN link with unneeded FTP data transfers, and may prompt FTP (with no-mirror / request-to-mirror policy) server's admin to deny access from your public IP as to them it appears the same as someone recursively downloading the entire site. That said, since we only want to get directory index, replacing "--spider" with a simple REGEX accept option "-A '.listing'" is a better choice as it causes wget to refuse downloading any data from the server except for ".listing" file(s).

P.S. @Codex24 - your oneliner to parse / report - nice work!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1124924)