# How to index ftp server on linux (preferably using gui)?

Tags: linux, ftp, opensuse, filezilla, directory-listing

Basically I'm using FileZilla right now but wouldn't mind to use any other gui. What I want is to index all directories and files in an ftp server so I can review them later (without the need of any connection to the original server). Any help will be appreciated - I'm using Opensuse Tumbleweed (latest updated) + KDE Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via CLI.

Use a command-line FTP client and run this command:

```
 dir -lR
```

or

```
 ls -R
```

which will list recursively the content of all directories and subdirectories.

Otherwise, without using a FTP client:

```
wget -r -x --no-remove-listing --spider ftp://ftp.example.com/
```

This will use wget to:

- retrieve recursively (`-r`) all directories and subdirectories,
- creating mirror subdirs on the client (`-x`)
- and hence a tree of directories on the client identical as the server but containing only `.listing` (`--no-remove-listing`) files showing the contents of each directory,
- without retrieving the files themselves (`--spider`).

Comment: For server without recursive listing support, [this](http://superuser.com/questions/423499/wget-only-getting-listing-file-in-every-sub-dir) may be useful

Comment: And what would this commands do? Can you explain their usage more? I would expect that they will simply output the directories and files on the stdout - is this true?

Comment: More or less. It will create a tree on your machine with a listing of directory contents in each directory. Answer updated.